# How to change styles of an html5 video using CSS events while playing

Tags: css, html, angular, animation, video

I would like to press a button and have the main video slide out to the right of the page.

Im using (psuedo code):

- .video { left: calc(50% - (half-width) }
- .button:focus ~ .video { left: (out of screen view)}

This has 0 effect.

Comment: Probably your `.button` is not focusable or `.video` is not a sibling of `.button`. It's difficult to say what's wrong exactly without seeing your code.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*